# ImageMagick failes to read a JPEG image

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

I've been using ImageMagick 6.9.0 for some time, and had setup some Railo scripts using it on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition machine a while back.  I know that they worked at the time.  I just tried to run them on a new set of images now, but ImageMagick is failing on the very first command:

```
<cfexecute name="#Application.ImageMagickRoot#\identify.exe" variable="imgResult" timeout="60" arguments="-format ""%w|%h"" ""#attributes.infoFullPath#""" />
```

The error returned is:

```
identify.exe: RegistryKeyLookupFailed `CoderModulesPath' @ error/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/662. identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501.
```

I've never seen anything like this.  So I checked and saw that there is a new version out, and downloaded IM 7.0.1.  I tried running the above command again with no changes, but this time pointing to the 7.0.1 install folder.  This resulted in a different, but similar, error:

```
identify.exe: unable to load module 'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_JPEG_.dll': The specified module could not be found. @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1275. identify.exe: no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/505.
```

I looked in the directory in the error and there is a file named IM_MOD_RL_jpeg_.dll there.

The images that I'm trying to work with are all different, and I've cycled through 50 or so during testing.  But all are between 4 and 10 megapixel photos exported from Photoshop CS5 Camera Raw to jpeg format.  I've tried fiddling with the case of the drive letter and the file extension without success.  A sample path to one of the images is:

```
c:\galleries_incoming\50\69\01 - Getting Ready\DSC_0001.JPG
```

I'm unsure what to try next.  I tried running this command per an old message on the IM forum to get a list of my decode delegates:

```
convert -list configure
```

But IM tells me that configure is not a valid list option.  In any case, it sounds like installing new decode delegates is something that requires a recompile, and I've just been relying on precompiled binaries (which I would assume would at least be able to read a jpeg).

Comment: I tracked this down to a permissions problem with IM 7.x.  I had full permissions given to "everyone" for the IM 7 install folder and all subfolders, but I still had to elevate the Railo service to run under an administrator level account to get it to work.  I don't understand why and would rather not have to leave it like this.

Even with those permission changes, IM 6.9.0 still reports the same error.

Comment: After a restart of the server the issue resumes, despite Railo running under an administrative account.